# Add/remove class on scroll with waypoints

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a class to each section, using jquery waypoints.
The point is that the class 'fixed', is to be added, when the section hits the top of the viewpoint, and then remove the class again for the previous section.

I have a push element in between each section, to secure the height of the fixed div in viewport.

The effect would look like a reverse full page curtain reveal.

Fiddle here:[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/vz3e94Lr/)

**Markup**

```
<section></section>
<div class="push"></div>
<section></section>
<div class="push"></div>
<section></section>
<div class="push"></div>
<section></section>
```

**CSS**

```
section {
height: 100vh;
z-index: 2;
}

.fixed {
position: fixed;
top:0;
width: 100%;
}

.push {
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$('section').each(function(){
        var sectionElement = $(this);
        var inview = new Waypoint.Inview({
            element: sectionElement[0],
            entered: function(direction) {
                if (direction === 'down') {
                    $('section').removeClass('fixed');
                    sectionElement.addClass('fixed');
                    sectionElement.prev().hide();
                } else {
                    sectionElement.removeClass('fixed');
                    sectionElement.prev().addClass('fixed');

                }
            },
        });
    });
```

Comment: Here is a **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/vz3e94Lr/)** for you.. Can you create exact problem demo with the above fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
.push {
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/vz3e94Lr/1/

Comment: I am trying to reverse the effect of the curtain reveal like used on curtain.js. Seems like I'm approaching it all wrong.